# View errors in subsetting

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset a dataframe and then view it. In the past this code has worked but now when I try it, it gives the error message "Error in View : 'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]". Here's the code that I've been running before

```
TD <- D111391[6:101,1]
TD[is.na(TD)] <- 0
TD <- as.numeric(as.character(TD))
```

where D111391 is just a dataset of [106,1] observations. lately this code has also been giving me the problem of shoving the entire subset into a single box as a vector of 96 observations. Can anyone tell me what my problem is with the getting View to work or why its slamming all my values into a single vector, thanks.

Comment: Please remember to `dput()` your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
TD <- D111391[6:101, 1, drop = FALSE]
TD[is.na(TD)] <- 0
TD[, 1] <- as.numeric(as.character(TD[, 1]))
```

TD will still be a data.frame with one column instead of a vector.

Dont know if this will solve it, I don't really know what do you pretend to do.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have solved the problem. The end goal was to get it into an 8 by 12 matrix and have it be numeric but my code has been acting weird lately. After I posted this question I opened another R file I had with the exact same code and it worked but your answer to the question fixes the original R script I had out, guess I'll have to do some digging and find out what's happening. Thank you!